# NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor conflits on Elastic Search jar

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, jar, guava

While creating Elasticsearch Client, I'm getting the exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor; 
After some lookup, seams like the Guava-18 is being overwrite by an older version at runtime, and Guava-18 only works during compile task.

My Maven configuration is the follow:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How can i force the Guava-18 version at execution time?

Comment: `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>latest</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should try to find where the "old" version of guava is taken from and to exclude it once for all.

Find the dependency :

`mvn dependency:tree | grep guava`

Exclude it :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.whatever</groupId>
  <artifactId>the_lib_that_includes_guava</artifactId>
  <version>0.97</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>com.google</artifactId>
      <groupId>guava</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html for more info on the dependency exclusion.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but i cant remove the older guava version, doesn't belong to my code.

Comment: Actually i solve it with that solution,  so thank you!

Comment: When I remove the old version, it still throw exception, because the old lib can not use guava.18, how can I fix this.

Comment: Just one comment about this solution: `mvn dependency:tree` does not always work, especially when working with fat-jars (because maven does not see these included dependencies). I found this out the hard way. To get a clue about these "classpath-problems", I'm using `org.basepom.maven:duplicate-finder-maven-plugin` for detection.

Comment: Please note that the given exclusion sample does not have correct group and artifact id. (groupId should be _com.google.guava_ and sample artifactId _guava-jdk5_)
Copy-paste incident :D

Comment: find the dependency with `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.google.guava`

Answer (score 4):

I add the correct dependency of elasticsearch resolve the problem

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `dependencyManagement` block solves this problem:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <!-- enforce dependency guava version 20.0 -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

---

Reference:

http://techidiocy.com/maven-dependency-version-conflict-problem-and-resolution/

Answer (score 1):

I was also seeing the error message mentioned by the OP when creating an Elasticsearch Client instance.  In my case it was occurring in a Spring Boot app at application startup.  Spring Boot was attempting to auto-configure the Elasticsearch Client via dependencies brought in by `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch`.  The underlying guava version being brought in was:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This was all working fine until I introduced the following `google-api-client` dependency...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

...which [depends on](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/blob/1.23.0/pom.xml) following guava dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
      <version>17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This caused a class path collision and the fix was to exclude the older guava version from the `google-api-client` like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best soltion is to use the shade plugin for maven. Adding this to your pom.xml should fix it:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>com.google.guava:guava</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This will create an upper jar with the same name including only a shaded guava inside.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I created a **.jar** file (Java source), then I wanted to load that file into the *Spark Shell*. It turns out that Spark Shell loads jars from something similar to this 
**spark-[version]-bin-hadoop[version]/jars/"**.

That directory had an older version of the guava which causes the error. I had the correct version in my **pom.xml**. I even added exclusions and all suggested responses. In conclusion, it is indeed a wrong version of guava. I copied the version that *matches* my pom.xml file. Hope this helps. Regards.

Comment: I see there is a *pom.xml* file in my project that is dynamically created using Guava version `24.0-jre`. Therefore I have added that version in my Gradle dependency however I am still seeing the error above.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I updated the Guava dependency to latest version and it solved the

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>latest</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This did not solve the issue for me @Himadri. As I can see from running the `gradle dependencies` command there are multiple versions of Guava being used in other libraries which seems related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue from past 2 months and finally found the solution.

I added too many external jars in my Project Structure which actually created some jars in Library Root resulting in conflicts whenever something is added in **pom.xml**.

So what needs to be done is delete all external jar files from your project and keep only the ones which are from maven like Maven:org...

My project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For SBT solution:

Use shading the library in build.sbt

```
// Shading com.google.**
// We need com.google.guava above 18 version but spark uses version 14 and in that we don't have directExecutor() method
// as spark give preference to spark used libraries, our code was failing

assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
    ShadeRule.rename("com.google.**" -> "shadeio.@1").inAll
)
```