# NetBeans + Glassfish --> NoSuchMethodError directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor

Tags: java, maven, google-translate, glassfish-4

Below exception happens when using the api google-cloud-translate.
I am developing a web application in NetBeans with application server Glassfish 4, JSF and bootfaces.

**Example code:**

```
public void traducir (String text){
Translate translate= TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();   
//Traduccion Inglés
Translation translation = translate.translate(text,TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("es"), TranslateOption.targetLanguage("en"));
 String traduccionIngles =  translation.getTranslatedText();
 System.out.println("Ingles traducido= " + traduccionIngles);
}
```

**This method throws below runtime exception**

```
    Advertencia:   #{subirFicheroManagedBean.traducirTextosNuevos()}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
javax.faces.FacesException: #{subirFicheroManagedBean.traducirTextosNuevos()}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.BasicRetryingFuture.<init>(BasicRetryingFuture.java:83)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:88)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:75)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl.translate(TranslateImpl.java:120)
    at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl.translate(TranslateImpl.java:138)
    at service.ServiceTraductor.traducirATodosLosIdiomas(ServiceTraductor.java:40)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more

Grave:   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)egy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.BasicRetryingFuture.<init>(BasicRetryingFuture.java:83)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:88)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:75)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl.translate(TranslateImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
```

**My pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cticontrol</groupId>
    <artifactId>traducionMvn</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>traducionMvn</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bootsfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootsfaces</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Dependencias JSF -->
        <!-- JSF 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Fin dependencias JSF -->
        <!-- Dependecias API TRADUCTOR GOOGLE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-translate</artifactId>
            <version>1.62.0</version>
             <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.28.0</version>
             <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>27.0.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Did you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157642/nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-util-concurrent-moreexecutors-directexecuto ?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `google-api-client` version `1.28.0` is [dependent](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/v1.28.0/pom.xml) on Guava  's `26.0-android` version. Instead of using guava `27.0.1-jre` dependency in your pom.xml try to change to the direct `-jre` android variant `26.0-jre`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>26.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
```

For more information on that there's a small [thread](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/issues/576#issuecomment-454972184) with this discussion.

Comment: I have tried changing the version of guava but I still get the same error.

I have done tests changing the version of guava (26.0-jre and 26.0-androi)
I have also changed the version of com.google.api-client (1.28.0 and 1.27.0)

Comment: Hi, I couldn't reproduce your issue. It may be useful for you to troubleshoot using  `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=com.google.guava`  command to find out any dependency conflict. `mvn dependency:tree | grep guava` should also work.

Comment: I have performed the actions that you have indicated to me and it has not worked for me.

In principle I have excluded the dependencies of all the jar and I have added jar of the guava and it keeps giving me the same error.

When I will publish the solution

There must be some conflict with Glassfish 4. Since I have made a test creating a new project, including the libraries by hand without maven and by console it works correctly.

I understand that the problem comes either with JSF or with Glassfish.


Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Hi Sergio, since it worked without maven, maybe this is an issue with the local maven repository keeping old dependencies. Check if deleting the maven `.m2` folder can solve the issue as it will force maven to re-download the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have executed the command "mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=com.google.guava"

    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --------------------< com.sample:traducionMvn >---------------------
    [INFO] Building traducionMvnPOM 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ traducionMvn ---
    [INFO] com.cticontrol:traducionMvn:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.0.1-jre:compile
    [INFO]    +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
    [INFO]    \- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  1.607 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-18T11:27:14+01:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


my pom is:
  <!-- Dependecias API TRADUCTOR GOOGLE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-translate</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>1.61.0</version> -->
            <version>1.62.0</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>com.google</artifactId>
                    <groupId>guava</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.28.0</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>com.google</artifactId>
                    <groupId>guava</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>27.0.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Fin dependencias API -->

------------------------------------
I keep giving the same error.
```

Comment: Is this a response to dhauptman comment? You should update the answer with this new information in order to be clearer.

Comment: You should update the answer with this information, also, did you tried: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157642/nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-util-concurrent-moreexecutors-directexecuto ?